# Deploy angular site on Firebase (FREE) using CLI

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, angular-cli, firebase-cli

How I can deploy an angular application on Firebase cloud for free using `CLI`. I just started practicing of angular 9 and Firebase cloud server to explore my self, and want to check how easy to deploy an app on Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploy angular/any site on Firebase absolutely free using below steps:

**Prerequisite**: Sign in into Firebase console using google account and then create project for angular app.

1. Add Firebase package in angular app

   CLI: `>ng add @angular/fire`
2. Install Firebase tools on your system

   CLI: `>npm install -g firebase-tools`
3. Make sure Firebase tools has been installed properly

   CLI: `>firebase --version`
4. Login into Firebase account

   CLI: `>firebase login`
5. Setup Firebase... You will be asked some options to set here

   CLI: `>firebase init`
6. Finally deploy the angular app on Firebase cloud

   CLI: `>firebase deploy`

Now we can see angular app running on Firebase server: `https://[firebase-project].web.app/`.

Answer (score 1):

The package `@angular/fire` has a built-in deploy functionality. You can read the documentation [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/deploy/getting-started.md).

Basically what you have to do to get your angular application running in firebase:

```
// this will guide you through the authentication system, and make the necessary changes
ng add @angular/fire

// now you can deploy your app
ng deploy
```

And you are done :)

If you want support for multiple projects you can re-run the previous commands, but then you include a `--project` parameter:

```
ng add @angular/fire --project=[PROJECT_NAME]
ng deploy --project=[PROJECT_NAME]
```